# What's wrong with the syntax of this simple MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_user AFTER DELETE

ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE max_id INT;
    DECLARE new_id INT;

    SELECT MAX(`id`) INTO max_id FROM `user`;
    IF max_id = NULL THEN
        SET max_id = 0;
    END IF

    SELECT `new_id` INTO new_id FROM `conf` WHERE `table` = 'user';

    IF max_id < new_id THEN
        UPDATE `conf` SET `new_id` = max_id WHERE `table` = 'user';
    END IF
END$$
```

I got following error prompt when I create this trigger:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SELECT new_id INTO new_id FROM conf WHERE table =
>   'fact'; IF max_id < new_id THEN ' at line 12

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Column and variable name is the same - try changing the variable name to sg else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing the query like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_user AFTER DELETE
ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE v_max_id INT;
    DECLARE v_new_id INT;

    SELECT MAX(`id`) INTO v_max_id FROM `user`;
    IF v_max_id IS NULL THEN
        SET v_max_id = 0;
    END IF;

    SELECT `new_id` INTO v_new_id FROM `conf` WHERE `table` = 'user';

    IF v_max_id < v_new_id THEN
        UPDATE conf c
            SET c.new_id = v_max_id
            WHERE c.`table` = 'user';
    END IF;
END$$
```

This mostly adds semicolons and fixes the `= NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your so prompt answer! Yes, you pointed out the two mistakes so accurately. My problem was solved. And I will adopt your naming habit, to add a 'v_' before local variables. Thank you very much!